# npm package and git, how should I handle data file

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I am working on building a npm package. In my package, I need to have a data folder which contains some json files to hold user data.

The issue is, I do want the user to have some blank data files when they first install the package. But I don't want:

1. When user used my package for a while and then do a version update, the newer version shouldn't overwrite user's existing data.
2. During development, my testing data in those files shouldn't be committed into git.

I have tried .gitignore for the second scenario, but once the file exists in the repository, it doesn't seem that .gitignore will work.

I am a bit confused here. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to give your library an options object for specifying which directory to read those json files from, with a default location.

Assuming your library is based on some top-level class:

```
const DEFAULT_DATA_PATH= ...
export default class Library {
  constructor(options={}) {
    this.dataPath = options.dataPath || DEFAULT_DATA_PATH;
  },
  ...
};
```

And if there is CLI invocation for your package, a runtime flag that lets you specify the location (like `--data ./ignored/realdata`) so that you can put your dev files in a dir that goes in your `.gitignore` and that you simply add as data dir flag in your npm run scripts.

```
const DEFAULT_DATA_PATH = ...
var dataPathOverride = process.argv.indexOf('--data') + 1;
dataPathOverride = dataPathOverride ? process.argv[dataPathOverride] : DEFAULT_DATA_PATH;

export default class Library {
  constructor(options={}) {
    this.dataPath = options.dataPath || dataPathOverride;
  },
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But how do I handle the npm situation?

Comment: I mean, if I have the blank data files in my repository. How do I keep user's data files untouched when they update their packages?

Comment: Same deal. Once a user `npm install`s your library, create a new (untracked) data dir for them, copy your blanks over, and from that point on check to see if that user dir exists. Does it? Great, use that dir. Does it not? Use the default "blank" files.